# Mean value for $\tiny\left( \begin{array}{cc} X & X \\ -X & 1-X \\ \end{array} \right)$

Tags: matrices

We have a matrix
$$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    X & X \\
    -X & 1-X \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
where $X$ is a random variable between $0$ and $1$. I heard about "random matrices". Is it an example of these matrices? Moreover, how we define a "mean" for these matrices? Since $X\in[0,1]$ I think that
$$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1/2 & 1/2 \\
    -1/2 & 1/2 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
is the mean of
$$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    X & X \\
    -X & 1-X \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
What do you think?

Comment: It depends on the distribution of $X$, obviously. $X\in[0,1]$ does not imply $\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If E(X)=.5 yes this the matrix of the means. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did Yes, I'm getting closer now to this topic and I have many doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean is taken entrywise, i.e.
$$
\mathbb E\pmatrix{X&X\\ -X&1-X}=\pmatrix{\mathbb EX&\mathbb EX\\ -\mathbb EX&1-\mathbb EX}.
$$